# Django Class Based Views: Is it considered wrong or bad to extend dispatch method?

Tags: python, django, class, methods, extends

In our django codebase, we extend dispatch method for the following reasons:

1. To set variables that are common to both GET/POST methods.
2. To restrict user access (For this created a separate mixin that just extends dispatch and does the checks)

If its considered bad, why is that and What is the alternative?

Comment: You can override `dispatch` method but make sure to call `super(View, sels).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Many (like me) understand python/django than plain english! :)

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar That is not necessary, as highlighted in the answer i posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, as long as overriding it is your only choice to get the functionality you need.

For example, `django-rest-framework` overrides the `dispatch` method to provide functionality like `authentication`, `permission`, `throttling`.

See [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L459-L486).

```
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        `.dispatch()` is pretty much the same as Django's regular dispatch,
        but with extra hooks for startup, finalize, and exception handling.
        """
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request
        self.headers = self.default_response_headers  # deprecate?

        try:
            self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)

            # Get the appropriate handler method
            if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
                handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(),
                                  self.http_method_not_allowed)
            else:
                handler = self.http_method_not_allowed

            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

        except Exception as exc:
            response = self.handle_exception(exc)

        self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.response
```

Comment: Can you add the documentation link to the claim you made *drf overrides* ? Thanks

Comment: @d-coder It is already present in the answer. But here it is : https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L459-L486

Comment: I didn't see the link. My bad!